# Conflict by launching an application

Tags: meteor

I get the following error by starting my application:

```
   While selecting package versions:
   error: Conflict: Constraint aldeed:autoform@4.2.0 is not satisfied by aldeed:autoform 5.7.1.
   Constraints on package "aldeed:autoform":
   * aldeed:autoform@5.2.0 <- top level
   * aldeed:autoform@4.2.0 <- meteoric:autoform-ionic 0.1.5
   * aldeed:autoform@5.7.0 <- forwarder:autoform-wizard 0.9.0
   * aldeed:autoform@4.0.0 || 5.0.0 <- notorii:autoform-datetimepicker 1.0.4
   * aldeed:autoform@4.0.0 || 5.0.0 <- lukemadera:autoform-googleplace 1.0.7
   * aldeed:autoform@4.0.0 || 5.0.0 <- cfs:autoform 2.2.1
```

Any ideas how to solve it? :)

Comment: the normal way to resolve package conflict is make a fresh project and try to put each package in the package file of the old project into the new package file until all the thing is resolved

Comment: Is there a way to do a kind of dedicated meteor add/update?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to update?

```
meteor update
```

Comment: Yes, I tried. I have a version 1.2.1 installed. After meteor update I get: While selecting package versions:
error: Conflict: Constraint aldeed:autoform@4.2.0 is not satisfied by aldeed:autoform 5.8.0.
Constraints on package "aldeed:autoform":
* aldeed:autoform@5.2.0 <- top level
* aldeed:autoform@4.2.0 <- meteoric:autoform-ionic 0.1.5
* aldeed:autoform@5.7.0 <- forwarder:autoform-wizard 0.9.0
* aldeed:autoform@4.0.0 || 5.0.0 <- notorii:autoform-datetimepicker 1.0.6
* aldeed:autoform@4.0.0 || 5.0.0 <- lukemadera:autoform-googleplace 1.0.7
* aldeed:autoform@4.0.0 || 5.0.0 <- cfs:autoform 2.2.1